# Flaws of mapping tables with auto incremented ID in sql

Tags: sql, database

I am currently developing ASP.NET Application & using SQL as backend.

I am having very serious problem with the DB. I am providing DB backup to the user.
If suppose Sql crashes and my client wants to  restore the DB with the backup.

As I have implemented my application by mapping table with the auto incremented ID column. So, If user will try to get the old data back from the Backup & that backup will have suppose 1 to 50 as auto incremented number in each table of the column and with respect to that DB will try to map that  data again on the basis of auto incremented column.

But AS DB crashed & auto increment column will not start from again 1. It will start respective count of the column  from 51.

Then all the mappings will go wrong and not a single table will give me the proper mapping information.

I have around 25 tables in my application.

Now, what will be the possible solution to get proper DB.

What should I do for mapping my table.

Please suggest me the best possible way to resolve this.

Comment: What is the problem?  The backup has the correct ids for the historical data.  New data gets new ids.  I don't see the problem.

Comment: nope dud I have read that this is the not safe way & not the standard way to  do the mapping there are so many possiblity that I can loss the whole bakcup. is there any way that I cant modify my all the table & will do mapping

Comment: can you please help me what should I do

Comment: I don't see any problem - any **decent** RDBMS (you didn't specify which one you're using....) should restore your data and the "state" (current last used ID) of each "auto-increment" columns. So the existing data in your backup that was restored should be just fine, and new rows being inserted should also be just fine - **where's the problem?**

Comment: After the crash does all the data still exist in your tables with the IDs 1-50 ?